# session variable value don't show

Tags: php, session

First.php

```
class SessionHandling implements SessionHandlerInterface {
    private $db ;

    public function open($path,$name) {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test",'root','') ;
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) ;
        if($db){
            $this->db = $db ;
            return true ;
        } else {
            return false ;
        }
    }

    public function close() {
        $db = null ;
        return true ;
    }

    public function read ($session_id) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT session_data FROM sessionhandler '.
            'WHERE session_id = :session_id  AND'.
            ' session_expire > :session_expire ') ;
        $query->bindParam(':session_id',$session_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':session_expire',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute() ;
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
        if(empty($result)){
            return "check again" ;
        } else {
            return $result[0]['session_data'] ;
        }
    }

    public function write ($id,$data) {
        $dataTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
        $newDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 month')) ;
        $query = $this->db->prepare('REPLACE INTO sessionhandler '.
            'SET session_id = :sessionId , session_data = :sessionData ,'.
            'session_expire = :sessionExpire ');
        $query->bindParam(':sessionId',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':sessionData',$data,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':sessionExpire',$newDateTime);
        $result = $query->execute() ;
        if($result){
            return true ;
        } else {
            return false ;
        }
    }

    public function destroy($id){
        $query = $this->db->prepare('DELETE from sessionhandler '.
            'WHERE session_id = :sessionId');
        $query->bindParam(':sessionId',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $result = $query->execute() ;
        if($result){
            return true ;
        } else {
            return false ;
        }
    }

    public function gc ($maxLife){
        $query = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM sessionhandler '.
            'WHERE session_expire < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :maxlife SECOND)');
        $query->bindParam(':maxlife',$maxLife);
        $result = $query->execute();
        if($result){
            return true ;
        } else {
            return false ;
        }
    }
}

$handler = new SessionHandling() ;
session_set_save_handler($handler,true) ;
```

second.php

```
require_once 'First.php' ;
session_start() ;
$_SESSION['var1'] = "asdfsadfsadf" ; 
$_SESSION['var2'] = "tytyrt" ;
```

third.php

```
require_once 'First.php'  ;
session_start() ; 
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    echo $_SESSION['var1']."<br>".$_SESSION['var2'] ; 
}
```

my session is storing in db but when i want see that value does't show on `third.php`. it will give error like var1 and var2  are undefined index .

second is that when i refresh thrid.php it will create blank session in db so would i avoid this .

Comment: where are you assigning values in session in first.php file? $_SESSION['var1'] = "asdfsadfsadf" ; 
  $_SESSION['var2'] = "tytyrt" ;

Comment: @DeepKakkar  i assigning values in different page but i inclue that customize file

Comment: please check Is your second.php runs before than third.php  file?

Comment: @DeepKakkar when i run second.php it will store values in my db but when i run third.php it show error

Answer (score 0):

You have set session in second.php and directly run third.php so session is not set . so please run second.php before third.php

otherwise you include

```
require_once 'First.php'  ;
require_once 'second.php' ; 
session_start() ; 
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    echo $_SESSION['var1']."<br>".$_SESSION['var2'] ; 
}
```

Comment: if i include the second.php than basically i echo on that page variable which will be shown definitely

Answer (score 0):

Does "session_start()" returns true? Can you get the session id with "session_id()"? Can you print the session_id for both files? Are the same?

If session_start returns false, try to call it again. Something like:

```
if (!session_start()) {
   session_start();
}
```

If the session_id is different instead means that you could have some problem with your session cookie (are you using some redirect to get from second.php to third.php)?

Comment: without session_start() how can i use $_SESSION global variable

Comment: they have same session_id